# How to instruct jQuery to destroy a UI Widget without removing its root element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, destructor

Is invoking "destroy" (native method) enough, or should I take additional measures like manually deleting the root element's data reference to the UI widget instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just invoking destroy is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Working with dialog for example, you have the option to `close` or `destory` it. `close` will hide the widget while `destroy' will remove it completely from the DOM.